# How to make a method wait for an accurate enough location before returning?

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

I have a class LocationHelper which I am designing to obtain a user location. On creation, I specify the accuracy required, and how current the location has to be. If it has to be a newly obtained location, or there is not a recent enough previous one then I want to start listening for updates from the location manager. My problem is that I want this to happen within one of the methods, and for the method not to return until an accurate enough location has been found. How do I stop the method from returning until I've got the location I want? I am only using the LocationHelper class from within a background service, so I don't care about it taking a long time to return.
I have thought of putting a while loop before the return which checks if position is null (it will be until an accurate enough position is found), and if it is then it will execute a wait, but am I right in thinking that this would block the listener from receiving updates?

The code is below if my explanation isn't clear enough (my problem is with getCurrentFix, at the bottom), thanks.

```
package com.s0812532.AutoBagger;

import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;


/**
 * Class LocationHelper
 * Class for obtaining the user's location. Capable of obtaining the current
 * position, or the most recent fix available fix without getting a new one, in
 * order to conserve battery power. Will automatically decide whether to use
 * GPS/network based on required accuracy. Must not be called directly from the UI
 * thread or the app will become unresponsive.
 */
public class LocationHelper {

    //
    // Fields
    //

    /**
     * The maximum accuracy, in metres, for the location fix to be considered accurate enough.
     */
    private int accuracyRequired;
    /**
     * The maximum age, in seconds, for the location fix to be considered recent enough.
     */
    private int ageRequired;
    /**
     * The Location obtained by the constructor
     */
    private Location position;
    /**
     * An instance of the system location manager.
     */
    private LocationManager lm;
    /**
     * The context passed in, in order to be able to access system resources like GPS.
     */
    private Context mCtx;
    /**
     * The current time, set by the constructor.
     */
    private long time;
    /**
     * A scaling factor which is applied to the accuracy of any network
     * based location fix to compensate for the inaccuracy of its reporting.
     */
    private static final float NETWORK_ACCURACY_SCALE = 5;

    //
    // Constructors
    //

    /**
     * Constructor which will get a location fix (current or recent) which meets the
     * criteria provided so that it can be acted on.
     * @return
     * @param        age The maximum age, in seconds, for the location fix to be
     * considered recent enough.
     * @param        accuracy The maximum accuracy, in metres, for the location fix to
     * be considered accurate enough.
     */
    public   LocationHelper( Context ctx, int age, int accuracy )
    {
        mCtx = ctx;
        setAgeRequired(age);
        setAccuracyRequired(accuracy);
        //Get the time (in milliseconds since UNIX epoch)
        //TODO - need to test what happens when phone clock is wrong
        Date now = new Date();
        time = now.getTime();
        //TODO - handle when LocationManager returns as null
        lm = (LocationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //Finally, get a fix to satisfy conditions (if a new fix is required then
        //getCurrentFix() will detect this and call getCurrentFix() itself.
        position = getRecentFix();
    }

    //
    // Methods
    //


    //
    // Accessor methods
    //

    /**
     * Set the value of accuracyRequired
     * The maximum accuracy, in metres, for the location fix to be considered accurate
     * enough.
     * @param newVar the new value of accuracyRequired
     */
    private void setAccuracyRequired ( int acc ) {
        //TODO - Test that value is not negative
        accuracyRequired = acc;
    }

    private void setAgeRequired ( int age ) {
        //TODO - Test that the value is not negative
        ageRequired = age;
    }


    //
    // Other methods
    //



    /**
     * Returns the location fix obtained by the constructor.
     * @return       Location
     */
    public Location getLocation(  )
    {
        return position;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the distance between the user's location and a location provided as an
     * argument.
     * @return       float
     * @param        location
     */
    public float getDistance( Location location )
    {
        return position.distanceTo(location);
    }


    /**
     * Obtains the most recent fixes from the GPS and Network location managers, and
     * stores the more accurate of the two if it is accurate/recent enough, otherwise
     * it will call getCurrentFix in order to get an accurate enough fix.
     * @return       Location
     */
    private Location getRecentFix(  )
    {
        //TODO - need to check if location sources are enabled, and deal with it if they aren't

        Location GPSFix = lm.getLastKnownLocation("GPS");
        Location networkFix = lm.getLastKnownLocation("network");
        //Adjust the stated accuracy of the network location fix due to errors in reporting
        networkFix.setAccuracy(networkFix.getAccuracy()/NETWORK_ACCURACY_SCALE);

        if( (GPSFix.getAccuracy() <  accuracyRequired ) & ( time - GPSFix.getTime() < ageRequired ) )
        {
            //Last GPS fix is good enough, so return it.
            return GPSFix;
        }
        else if ( ( networkFix.getAccuracy() < accuracyRequired ) & ( time - networkFix.getTime() < ageRequired ) )
        {
            //Last network fix is good enough, so return it.
            return networkFix; 
        }
        else  {
            //none of the available fixes are good enough, so obtain a new one.
            return getCurrentFix();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Obtains either a GPS or Network based LocationManager, and gets a new fix, if
     * possible. GPS/Network is decided upon based accuracy required.
     * @return       Location
     */
    private Location getCurrentFix(  )
    {
        //TODO - need to put in some sort of timeout (perhaps getting status updates will do)

        LocationListener networkListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                //check to see if new position is accurate enough
                if (loc.getAccuracy() < accuracyRequired) {
                    position = loc;
                }
                else if (new Date().getTime() - time > 15000 ) { //if it has been looking for network location updates for 15 seconds or more
                    //Get updates from GPS instead
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, GPSListener);
                }
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO - network location is/has been disabled by user - do something like warn user it is a bad idea

            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        LocationListener GPSListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                // TODO - check to see if new position is accurate enough
                if (loc.getAccuracy() < accuracyRequired) {
                    position = loc;
                }
                else if (new Date().getTime() - time > 60000 ) { //if it has been looking for GPS location updates for 60 seconds or more
                    //TODO Report an error getting location
                }
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO - GPS is/has been turned off by user - do something like warn user it is a bad idea

            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };



        if(accuracyRequired < 200) {
            //First try network updates, then use GPS if sufficient accuracy not obtained in time
            lm.requestLocationUpdates("network", 0, 0, networkListener);
        }
        else {
            //GPS updates required for accuracy
            lm.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, GPSListener);
        }

        while (position == null){
            //Do nothing, this is just to stop the method returning the position until it has been set
            try {
                wait(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return position;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location listener callbacks are made on the main thread, so you cannot block the main thread (otherwise your listener callbacks will never happpen). If your Service is running in the same process as your activities then this is also the UI thread. In order to make this work you need to ensure that your `LocationHelper` is running in a separate thread. Then you can add a `while` loop that sleeps a bit between checks for a new location. As I said earlier, since the location listener callbacks happen on the main thread there will be no blocking.

Can you be more specific when you say this is running in a **background service**. What exacly do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean it is a service which runs in a different thread from the main UI and has no user interaction whatsoever. I think your answer solves my problem though. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. I just wanted to be sure you understood that even a Service has calls that execute on the main thread and that if your service is in the same process as your activites (which is the default behaviour) that you could block them.